# How can I append a Razor value to a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, append

I need to append multiple date pikers so I have a jQuery function to append the controls. 
This is what I need to append:

```
 @Html.DatePickerFor(x => x.EndDate, new { @class = "form-control col-lg-8 datepicker", @id = "" })
```

with

```
$('.multipleShareHolders').append("");
```

I think I should create a razor variable with the content I want to render before append.

Comment: `$('.multipleShareHolders').append($('.datepicker'));`?

Comment: @DenseCrab That answers my question, thanks